# How to find out information regarding xp_passAgentInfo

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know what the procedure `xp_passAgentInfo` is?

What I have found in Internet is that this procedure is an undocumented one.

Comment: You could always open a Premier Support ticket with Microsoft to find out, but I suspect you won't get a satisfactory answer about the purposes and workings of xp_* procedures.

Answer (score 0):

`xp_passAgentInfo` is an old **Undocumented Extended Procedure** going back as far as *SQL Server 2005*. You were correct there is no information or documentation about `xp_passAgentInfo` available from Microsoft.

Here are some other examples of other Undocumented Extended Procedures:

```
sp_resyncexecute
sp_resyncexecutesql
sp_resyncprepare
sp_resyncuniquetable
sp_SetOBDCertificate
sp_setuserbylogin
sp_update_user_instance
xp_adsirequest
xp_cleanupwebtask
xp_convertwebtask
xp_MSADEnabled
xp_MSADSIObjReg
xp_MSADSIObjRegDB
xp_MSADSIReg
xp_msx_enlist
```